# unistd.h's read() inside a loop

Tags: c++, linux, loops, inotify

I have a trouble in getting this loop to work.

```
const char* filename = "test.txt";

int inotfd = inotify_init();

int watch_desc = inotify_add_watch(inotfd, filename, IN_MODIFY);


size_t bufsize = sizeof(struct inotify_event) + PATH_MAX + 1;

struct inotify_event* event = (inotify_event*)malloc(bufsize);

while (true) {

    read(inotfd, event, bufsize);

    //Does smth here
}
```

The problem is that it loops only once. After first `Does smth here` line the loop ends.

Additionally, I am using `inotify` to know when the text file is modified outside of the application. `read()` just waits for file to be modify, so I need it inside a loop.

Comment: there is no keyword `true` in C. do you `#include <stdbool.h>`?

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin I am coding in c++, but tagged C because this is more C related. I want the loop's condition to be always true

Comment: I see. what happens after "the loop ends"? does your program ever terminate? Also, you might want to consider retagging your question to c++.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Alright, that's true.

Comment: You say: The loop ends. Are you sure the loop ends and not the complete thread? You should check if - when you add a "printf" instruction after the loop - if this instruction is executed or not.

Comment: @MartinRosenau I thought about it and used it outside the thread too but I have the same problem. I have debugged and it jumps out of the loop after the last line of loop's body.